# How to access a String function with PHP?

Tags: php, css, csscrush

I am using the PHP CSS preprocessor [CssCrush](http://the-echoplex.net/csscrush) for the first time and I am needing to implement the [`csscrush_string()`](http://the-echoplex.net/csscrush/#api--functions) function into my custom assets manager. Previously I was using [CssMin](https://code.google.com/p/cssmin/) but now I need use of the preprocessor.

The following snippet below obviously has a syntax error at `$data = csscrush_string( string $string [, array $options ] );` and I do not know how to correct it.

I have also tried: `$data = Crush::csscrush_string();` but I get `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Crush' not found...` even-though `Crush` is a class.

**Using CssCrush** (replacing CssMin):

```
<?php

private function process_resource($file, $type)
{
     //...Files are combined and dumped into $data up here
    // before running the preprocessor and minifier...

    $data = str_replace($keys, $vals, $data);
    $css_lib = VENDOR_DIR . "css-crush/css-crush/CssCrush.php";
    if ($this->settings[$type]["minify"])
    {
        require $css_lib;
        $data = csscrush_string( string $string [, array $options ] );
        $data = trim($data);
    }
}
```

**Using CssMin** (works):

```
<?php

$data = str_replace($keys, $vals, $data);
css_lib = VENDOR_DIR . "natxet/CssMin/src/CssMin.php";
if ($this->settings[$type]["minify"])
{
    require $css_lib;
    $data = CssMin::minify($data);
    $data = trim($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just guess because I don't know what $data contains but it seems to be string

change

```
 $data = csscrush_string( string $string [, array $options ] );
 $data = trim($data);
```

to

```
 $data = csscrush_string(trim($data));
```

I've checked source of this function and there is only one option to be passed called 'boilerplate' if you want to pass it then you should invoke function as below

```
 $data = csscrush_string(trim($data), array('boilerplate' => true));
```

Also consider that this function is within namespace so you should put

`use \CssCrush\Crush\csscrush_string;` or class function like

```
  $data = \CssCrush\Crush\csscrush_string(trim($data));
```